# If a executable redis's lua script fail to return value to client (java application), is that transaction rolled back or not?

Tags: redis, lua

Here is my Lua script.

```
local field = ARGV[1]
local amount = ARGV[2]

local newAmount = redis.call("HINCRBYFLOAT", key, field, amount)
return newAmount
```

I have this lua script in my java application. My concern is if this script fail to return "newAmount" then the script's transactions will roll back or not?

My expectation is the roll back operation should happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no automatic rollbacks of transactions in Redis Lua scripts. The executed commands are not rolled back in the event of an failure later in the script. In fact, [rollbacks in Redis doesn't exist at all](https://redis.io/docs/interact/transactions/#what-about-rollbacks).

But there are [discussions](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/10576) about implementing some kind of rollback feature.

Important [definition](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/eval-intro/) of "atomically":

> Redis guarantees the script's atomic execution. While executing the script, all server activities are blocked during its entire runtime.

That means that Redis treats the complete script as one operation with no other operation interrupting it.

To prevent errors you should validate all your input arguments very thoroughly before using them. To handle potential errors, you can use [`redis.pcall()`](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/lua-api/#a-nameredispcalla-redispcallcommand-arg) instead of `redis.call()`. With `redis.pcall()` you can handle runtime errors that are raised by Redis as `redis.pcall()` always returns a reply and never throws a runtime exception. This can be helpful in creating your own rollback logic and to [log](https://redis.io/docs/interact/programmability/lua-api/#a-nameredisloga-redisloglevel-message) errors.

Example:

```lua
local function scriptNoRollback(keys)
    redis.call("INCR", keys[1])
    redis.call("INCR", keys[2])

    return "OK"
end

local function scriptRollback(keys)
    -- Store initial value.
    local initValueCounter1 = redis.call("GET", keys[1])

    redis.call("INCR", keys[1])
    local reply = redis.pcall("INCR", keys[2])
    if type(reply) == "table" and reply["err"] ~= nil then
        reply["err"] = "Oops, error!"
        -- Try to rollback data.
        redis.call("SET", keys[1], initValueCounter1)

        return reply
    end

    return "OK"
end
```

`scriptNoRollback` OK:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MSET counter1 1 counter2 2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FCALL scriptNoRollback 2 counter1 counter2
"OK"
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET counter1 counter2
1) "2"
2) "3"
```

`scriptNoRollback` ERR:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MSET counter1 1 counter2 A
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FCALL scriptNoRollback 2 counter1 counter2
(error) ERR value is not an integer or out of range script: scriptNoRollback, on @user_function:118.
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET counter1 counter2
1) "2"
2) "A"
```

`counter1` is not rolled back to initial state.

`scriptRollback` OK:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MSET counter1 1 counter2 2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FCALL scriptRollback 2 counter1 counter2
"OK"
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET counter1 counter2
1) "2"
2) "3"
```

`scriptRollback` ERR:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> MSET counter1 1 counter2 A
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FCALL scriptRollback 2 counter1 counter2
(error) Oops, error!
127.0.0.1:6379> MGET counter1 counter2
1) "1"
2) "A"
```

`counter1` is rolled back to initial state.

Comment: Actually, I am facing a network problem on getting return value. How can I assure that

Comment: @Md.SaifulIslam It's really tricky to handle all types of errors. I have updated my answer with more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. But what if script failed to execute this "return newAmount" line of code?

Comment: @Md.SaifulIslam I have updated my answer with an example that hopefully answers your question and other questions regarding what happens in a script.

Answer (score 1):

In Redis, Lua scripts do not support traditional transactions like you might find in a relational database management system (RDBMS). Redis doesn't have built-in support for multi-statement transactions with rollback capabilities like ACID transactions in RDBMS systems.

The Lua script you've provided is an atomic operation, meaning it will either succeed entirely or fail entirely. It's not a transaction in the traditional database sense, and it doesn't have the concept of rollback in case of failure.

In your Lua script, if an error occurs (for example, due to invalid arguments or a Redis server issue), the script won't return a value, and your Java application won't receive a response. However, it won't trigger a rollback of previous Redis operations.

If you need transaction-like behavior in Redis, you can use Redis's built-in MULTI/EXEC transaction mechanism. You can queue multiple commands using MULTI, and then execute them atomically with EXEC. If any of the commands fail, the entire transaction is rolled back. However, Lua scripts do not inherently participate in this transaction mechanism.

In summary, your Lua script, as written, doesn't provide transaction-like behavior with rollback. If you want to ensure transactions in Redis, you should use the MULTI/EXEC mechanism and not rely solely on Lua scripts for that purpose.